# SoapObject in android application

Tags: android, soap

Here is some fragment of my android application code PerformDownload.java

public class PerformDownload {

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:4304/Service1.asmx";

public String GetContacts(String username) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
//  String result = null;

    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetContacts";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "GetContacts";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

request.addProperty("username",username);

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new          SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; // put this only if the web service is .NET one
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    KvmSerializable response=   (KvmSerializable)envelope.bodyIn;
```

I am getting error on SoapObject,SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); and so on.
Why the above code is not accessing soap protocol.